# wordpress duplicate the custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I have made a template custom type with custom field. What I need to do is make a copy of that post so that all the data and custom field could be copied to new custom post type. So that I could change the certain part of that project.
Might be some plugin m looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a plugin for dublicating the post types
please check the link here the plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicate-post/. it provides a clone option on the list where quick edit resides